# Firebase / advanced filters on server side to limit user access using access rights

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

He there,

Here is my situation (simplified because in reality I have many more elements in my database)

I have 3 elements in Firebase :

1 - a list of access rights, for example:

```
{ id: 'G01' }
```

2 - a list of users with various attributes and a list of access rights, for example:

```
{ 
   id: '800', 
   name: 'rachel', 
   groups: {
       G01: true, 
       G02: true
   }
}
```

3 - a list of messages with various attributes and a list of access rights, for example:

```
{ 
   id: '430', 
   content: 'hi there', 
   groups: {
       G01: true,
       G03: true
   }
},
{ 
   id: '650', 
   content: 'hi there', 
   groups: {
       G03: true
   }
}
```

**My goal is to only return to the client side the messages for which the user is authorized** (for example 'rachel' must only see the messages with groups G01 and G02 : the id='430' message) **while maintaining the real time side of Firebase**

I know that this filter can be done on the client side before and / or after the request to the server but I do not want to leave the possibility to the user to intercept the request and modify the filters (for security reasons)

I studied the Firebase functions on server side but it concerns only changes in the database (write, delete, create)

I also studied the system of rules accessible in the console but, unless I am mistaken, can not answer to my need with.

Does anyone have a track to handle this kind of need?
In advance thank you all for your help.

Comment: I can't work out how to do it based on your example data, one suggestion is you'll need to flatten the `message` object and move `G01` into the parent object. Then review how Query Based Rules work (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules). You might be able to find a solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I actually think that the change of model is a key, the use of firestore instead of firebase another one because the security rules more complete.